# submiting a form with jquery and ajax but no submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that contains a table with sortable rows. The sorting works fine, the position of the row sort is stored in a database. The saving is done by submitting the form and an ajax call.

In a previous version I did the submitting with a button, and this code worked just fine saving everything in the database. Now I want to eliminate the button, because users tend to forget to press save.

Now after moving a row up or down the updateProductSortOrder() function is called, but the form is not submitted.

I read through many questions here on stackoverflow, and other resources, and I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

```js
var bundleApiUrl = 'bundleApi.php';
if (typeof jQuery.fn.sortable !== "undefined") {
  $(function () {
    $('#sortableRows').sortable({
      start: function (event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.index();
        ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
      },
      update: function (event, ui) {
        var index = ui.item.index();
        var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');

        //update the html of the moved item to the current index
        $('#sortableRows tr:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ') .sortOrder').html(index);
        $('#sortableRows tr:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ') .sortOrderValue').val(index);

        if (start_pos < index) {
        //update the items before the re-ordered item
          for (var i = index; i > 0; i--) {
            $('#sortableRows tr:nth-child(' + i + ') .sortOrder').html(i - 1);
            $('#sortableRows tr:nth-child(' + i + ') .sortOrderValue').val(i - 1);
          }
        } else {
        //update the items after the re-ordered item
          for (var i = index + 2; i <= $("#sortableRows tr .sortOrder").length; i++) {
            $('#sortableRows tr:nth-child(' + i + ') .sortOrder').html(i - 1);
            $('#sortableRows tr:nth-child(' + i + ') .sortOrderValue').val(i - 1);
          }
        }
        updateProductSortOrder();
      },
      axis: 'y'
    });
  });
}
function updateProductSortOrder() {
  var form = document.getElementById('updateSortOrder');
  $("#updateSortOrder").submit(
    $.ajax({
      url: bundleApiUrl,
      method: 'POST',
      data: new FormData(form),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#err").fadeOut();
      },
      success: function (result) {
        var resultArray = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(resultArray);
      },
      error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

```css
.row-resize {
  cursor: row-resize;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form name="updateSortOrderForm" method="post" id="updateSortOrder" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="hidden" name="bundleId" value="180" />
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sort order</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Model</th>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Group Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="sortableRows">
          <tr id="unique-2" class="row-resize">
            <td class="sortOrder">0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Matrox G400 32MB</td>
            <td>MG400-32MB</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Graphic Cards</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="unique-1" class="row-resize">
            <td class="sortOrder">1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Matrox G200 MMS</td>
            <td>MG200MMS</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Graphic Cards</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="unique-5" class="row-resize">
            <td class="sortOrder">2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro</td>
            <td>MSIMPRO</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Mice</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="unique-6" class="row-resize">
            <td class="sortOrder">3</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Microsoft IntelliMouse Explorer</td>
            <td>MSIMEXP</td>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>Mice</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="unique-3" class="row-resize">
            <td class="sortOrder">4</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Microsoft Internet Keyboard PS/2</td>
            <td>MSINTKB</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <input type="hidden" name="view" value="updateSortOrder" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What approach would you like? Save button does seem like the most applicable solution, because other solutions would require the form to be sent upon other actions where the user might not even be ready to send in the form. What you could do, is add javascript that reminds the user to press save/send or whatever at the end of the form, or when they try to leave without having pressed save/send.

Comment: if you use [`submit`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) with no argument it is the same as clicking on a submit button

Comment: @Martin
Thanks, but that will in my mind over-complicate things. Also if the user accepts the default sorting, no action is required.

Comment: @jonatjano
Can you add an example, asI amnot that familiar with javascript/jquery. I am dangerous enough to copy paste and alter, but that is it.

Comment: Then you could fire your function via onchange on the last user input. `onchange="functionName();"` But again, this will submit the form upon leaving the last input field. That means, if the user starts on the last input field, but for some reason switches to another because he/she realizes they forgot something in the previous input fields, or whatever, it will still save/send the form. That is what my concern was initially and why I proposed what I did previously.

Comment: what I propose is to replace everything in `updateProductSortOrder` by `$("#updateSortOrder").submit ()` because `submit(function (){})` will launch the function when the `EventSubmit` is launched from the element while `submit()` (without argument) will submit the form as if you clicked on a `<button type="submit">`

Comment: @Martin I think you mis understood my question. The form saves the row positions of a table. The user uses his mouse to slide the rows up and down. When the sort changes updateProductSortOrder() is fired, but the form will not submit.

Comment: @jonatjano Okay, that at least fired up the rest of the code, but with no data.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. You want to save the order of the table, correct? The way you can do that without a button is that after every sorting action, you either do `onchange` upon the element, `onblur` or add a `submit()` event. `onchange` will fire the function once a user has changed something, but not dynamically like `onkeyup` for instance. `onblur` fires the function once the input loses focus (bit like same approach as onchange), `submit()` simply acts as if a `<button type="submit">` had been pressed.

Comment: @Zen4All it send the data in the form selected by `$("#updateSortOrder")`   if try to look at the content of your input it may be empty

Comment: @jonatjano I got it working, but needed to add a variable to capture the form data. "new Formdata(this)" kept returning empty
See my updated code for the result

Comment: @Zen4All post your solution as an answer for future visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was given in the coments, but I will post them here too

1. replace everything in updateProductSortOrder by $("#updateSortOrder").submit () because submit(function (){}) will launch the function when the EventSubmit is launched from the element while submit() (without argument) will submit the form as if you clicked on a
2. Added `var form = document.getElementById('updateSortOrder');`, because `new FormData(form)` would not populate

Thank you @jonatjano and @Martin for your help

The code example has been updated

Answer (score 0):

Use the onblur event. With the button you probably had a onclick event.

Comment: Can you eleborate a bit? Where do I add the onblur ?

Comment: To the element that is left by the user when you want to save the data. I assume you have an input field or such.